# How to get text of every text node in Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, cheerio

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
foo
</div>
```

I want to get only the text of the text nodes inside the div, and I can't use `$('div').text()` because that gives me the text of the `p` also.

Actually I would like to get the text of every such text node, and I hope there's something as simple as `$('textNode').toArray().map((node) => $(node).text())`.

Comment: Try: `var node = document.getElementById('test');textContent = node.textContent;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a text that's separated by different HTML tags in Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73690939/how-to-get-a-text-thats-separated-by-different-html-tags-in-cheerio)